# Modify awk script to add looping logic

Tags: unix, awk, aix

I have an awk script to print pids appearing in myfilename. Where myfilename contains a list of pids each one appearing on a new line...

```
ps -eaf | awk -f script.awk myfilename -
```

And here is the contents of script.awk...

```
# process the first file on the command line (aka myfilename)
# this is the list of pids
ARGIND == 1 {
    pids[$0] = 1
}

# second and subsequent files ("-"/stdin in the example)
ARGIND > 1 {
    # is column 2 of the ps -eaf output [i.e.] the pid in the list of desired
    # pids? -- if so, print the entire line
    if ($2 in pids)
        printf("%s\n",$0)
}
```

At the moment the comman prints out pids in order of the ps -eaf command however I would like it to print out pids as per the order that they appear in myfilename.

I tried to modify the script to loop through $pids and repeat the same logic but I couldn't quite get it right.

Appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the output of `ps -eaf` looks like on your system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive my rusty AWK. Perhaps this is usable?

```
ARGIND == 1 {
    pids[$0] = NR # capture the order
}

ARGIND > 1 {
    if ($2 in pids) {
        idx = pids[$2];
        matches[idx] = $0; # capture the line and associate it with the ps -eaf order
        if (idx > max)
            max = idx;
    }
}

END {
    for(i = 1; i <= max; i++)
        if (i in matches)
            print matches[i];
}
```

I don't know what the output from `ps -eaf` looks like or what assumptions might be useful to exploit from its output. When I first read the question I thought OP had more than two inputs to the script. If it's really going to be only two then it probably makes more sense to reverse the inputs, if not then this might be the more general approach.

Comment: Thanks. This tool a while for me to understand and put into my code but I got it to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would instead do this using the time-honoured `NR==FNR` construct.  It goes a little something like this (one-liner).

```
ps -eaf | awk 'NR==FNR{p[$1]++;next} $2 in p' mypidlist -
```

The idea of `NR==FNR` is we look at the current record number (NR), and compare it to the record number *within the current file* (FNR). If they are the same, we are in the same file, so we store a record and move to the next line of input.

If `NR==FNR` is *not* true, then we simply check for `$2` being in the array.

So the first expression populates the array `p[]` with the contents of `mypidlist`, and the second construct is a condition only, which defaults to `{print}` as its statement.

Of course, the one-liner above does not address your requirement to print results in the order of your pid input file.  To do that, you need to keep an index and record the data in an array for some kind of sort.  Of course, it doesn't have to be a *real* sort, just keeping the index itself should be sufficient.  The following is a bit long as a one-liner:

```
ps -eaf | awk 'NR==FNR{p[$1]++;o[++n]=$1;next} $2 in p {c[$2]=$0} END {for(n=1;n<=length(o);n++){print n,o[n],c[o[n]]}}' mypidlist -
```

Broken out for easier reading, the awk script looks like this:

```
# Record the pid list...
NR==FNR {
  p[$1]++            # Each pid is an element in this array.
  o[++n]=$1          # This array records the order of the pids.
  next
}

# If the second+ input source has a matching pid...
$2 in p {
  c[$2]=$0           # record the line in a third array, pid as key.
}

END {
  # At the end of our input, step through the ordered pid list...
  for (n=1;n<=length(o);n++) {
    print c[o[n]]    # and print the collected line, using our pid index as key.
  }
}
```

Note that in the event a pid from your list is missing from `ps` output, the result will be to print a blank line, since awk doesn't complain about references to nonexistent array indices.

Note also that `length(arrayname)` notation works in GAWK and [OneTrueAwk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk), but may not be universal. If that doesn't work for you, you might be able to add an something like this to your awk script:

```
function alength(arrayname,    i, n) {
  for(i in arrayname)
    n++
  return n
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the "the order that they appear in myfilename" bit of the question but swapping the argument order (and associated fields, etc.) would do that I think.

Comment: @EtanReisner - darn, right you are. Not sure how I missed that. Added code to handle that extra condition.

Answer (score 1):

If there is one file, you can flip the order of inputs and use idiomatic `awk` as follows

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} $0 in a{print a[$0]}' <(ps -eaf) <(seq 10)

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 02:36 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         5     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u30:0]
root         7     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root         8     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/0]
root         9     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/1]
root        10     2  0 02:36 ?        00:00:00 [rcuos/2]
```

Here, the list of the ids provided by the `seq`, substitute with your file.

Comment: I guess it's a toss-up whether recording the entire process table in an array will be more performant than storing only the important lines in an array and then traversing an array in a loop in `END`.  But .. nicely done indeed.  (Might I suggest you remove the process redirection, since we don't know if the OP's AIX host has it installed?)